# Accidentally fires click with touchend

Tags: jquery, touch, touch-event

I have a mouseover and mouseout event connected to some image Links with a click event that fires a popup on my website. When using a smartphone this gave me an extra click that I wanted to remove and I found the solution to add `.on` and `touchend` and the problem seemed to be solved, but now I realize that when I try to scroll I accidentally click the imageLink all the time and the popup fires. Any suggestions for a simple solution?

**Javascript**

```
$('.ImageLink').on('click touchend', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

...popup function
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here, but maybe you can check if `e.type == 'click'`.

Answer (score 3):

On touchstart store the Y position of the touch event in a variable. 
On touchend compare the Y position of the touch event to the Y position you have stored. 
If the difference between both is less than X do your popup function. 
If the distance between both is bigger than X, that mean it's a scroll, don't do anything.

**Javascript**

```
var startY,endY, deltaY;

$('.ImageLink')[0].addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);
$('.ImageLink')[0].addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);
$('.ImageLink')[0].addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, false);

function handleTouchStart(e) {
    if (e.touches.length == 1) {
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        startY = touch.pageY;
        deltaY = 0;
    }
}

function handleTouchMove(e) {
    if (e.touches.length == 1) {
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        endY = touch.pageY;
        deltaY = endY - startY;
    }
}

function handleTouchEnd(e) {
    if (e.touches.length == 0) { // User just took last finger off screen
        if (Math.abs(deltaY) < 40) { // User didn't move finger much up or down
            alert('Popup code here')
        } else {
            alert('Do nothing')
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4hmhs/

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a plan. Not sure how to write this with the other code though. I'm a beginner to jquery.

Comment: I added an example, hope this help you :)

Comment: Thank you so much Simon, how do I combine it with the original click event that I had in my solution. The reason I put touchend in there was to over ride the mouseover / mouse out on the smartphone. Still not sure how to put these two solutions together.